# Kendo UI Grid - load remote data (query string url) + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, datasource

My `API` url to get data is `GET` request with multiple query strings:

```
"api/GetSomeData?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3"
```

and returned data is `array` of `JSON` objects.

I have to load initial `dataSource` for my kendo ui grid where `value1`, `value2` and `value3` have initial values (for example 1, 2 and 3).

Then, while clicking on some buttons on my page, `dataSource` should be changed, I mean there should be same `GET` request but with different `value1, value2, value3` values. I use AngularJS on frontend.

How to set `dataSource` object (transport, read etc.) in KendoUI grid options?

What came to my mind is to create `$scope.params` object with initial values, and when clicking on desired buttons, update that object of params with desired values, and then call `refresh()` method of kendo grid?

Comment: if you do this, are you sending the data back to the controller to update the data or are you just updating the page, so when you refresh the new results won't show

Comment: There is no sending data back to API. Just `GET` requests and I need to change kendo `dataSource`  to new returned data.

Comment: then use a databound event and change it that way